# How do I make this HUD bullet counter work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make this piece of code work, but I can't figure out on my own, why it doesn't. I got six bullets icons on my HUD and each time I shoot each icon become false (Deactivate), that's the idea. BTW, its Unity.

```
void Bullets(Image[] bullets, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < weapons[index].ammoAmount; i++)
    {
        bullets[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

ammoAmount has a value of 6 which represent every bullet icon on my HUD, each time I shoot I use something like this:

```
void Shooting()
{
    if (Input.GetButton(DualShock4.Input(InputCode.L2)))
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown(DualShock4.Input(InputCode.R2)))
        {
            if (weapons[1].ammoAmount > 0) weapons[1].ammoAmount -= 1;
            else if (weapons[2].ammoAmount > 0) weapons[2].ammoAmount -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware Bullets() method only keep my icons activated, I have no idea how to deactivate, "for loop" it's out of my control. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope its because, you don't deactivate the bullet. Have two variables named 'ammoAmount', and 'shotBullets'. I haven't tried out the code below. But, the idea is like this.

```
oid Shooting()
{
    if (Input.GetButton(DualShock4.Input(InputCode.L2)))
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown(DualShock4.Input(InputCode.R2)))
        {
            if (weapons[1].ammoAmount > weapons[1].shotBullets) weapons[1].shotBullets += 1;
            else if (weapons[2].ammoAmount > weapons[2].shotBullets) weapons[2].shotBullets += 1;
        }
    }
}


void Bullets(Image[] bullets, int index)
{
    int liveAmmo = weapons[index].ammoAmount - shotBullets; 
    for (int i = 0; i < weapons[index].ammoAmount; i++)
    {
        bullets[i].gameObject.SetActive((i<liveAmmo));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## You need a max ammo value

```
void Bullets(Image[] bullets, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < weapons[index].maxAmmoAmount; i++)
    {
        bullets[i].gameObject.SetActive(i < weapons[index].ammoAmount);
    }
}
```

That way your loop is over the *total* ammo capacity and then the objects are set active/inactive based on whether or not `i` (the bullet image number) is less than the remaining ammo (remembering that `i = 0` is the same thing as  `bullets I have left = 1`).

Of course, if all your weapons have the same amount of ammo capacity, you could just do `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)`, but it's less refactorable later.

`SetActive(i < weapons[index].ammoAmount)` is just a short way of doing:

```
if(i < weapons[index].ammoAmount)
    SetActive(true)
else
    SetActive(false)
```

As `(i < weapons[index].ammoAmount)` is already a boolean value, rather than performing an if-check, we can just send that boolean *to* the `SetActive()` method directly.